# Does yum-cron need to be enabled at boot to download and install updates?

Tags: centos, cron

**Operating system:** CentOS 7.6.1810

**Question:** Does `yum-cron` need to be enabled at boot to download and install updates?

**Background:** This is the location and contents of my `cron.daily` file.

`/etc/cron.daily/0yum-daily.cron`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Only run if this flag is set. The flag is created by the yum-cron init
# script when the service is started -- this allows one to use chkconfig and
# the standard "service stop|start" commands to enable or disable yum-cron.
if [[ ! -f /var/lock/subsys/yum-cron ]]; then
  exit 0
fi

# Action!
exec /usr/sbin/yum-cron
```

Although I'm not an expert I believe that `0yum-daily.cron` runs every day and when it does it instructs `yum-cron` to execute.  Is that all I need?

I ask because 2 different tutorials say to start `yum-cron` at boot with the enable command.

`systemctl enable yum-cron`

Maybe I'm missing something but is that necessary?  Why would `yum-cron` need to be enabled when the system boots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to enable and start the `yum-cron.service` unit.

The cron.daily and cron.hourly entries you see there check for the file named `/var/lock/subsys/yum-cron` and refuse to run if it is absent. But this file is only created by the init system on EL6 and older. It does not exist on EL7 and later. The `yum-cron.service` unit creates this file when it starts, and deletes the file when it stops, thus enabling or disabling the cron jobs, respectively.

Comment: I just confirmed your answer in bash and you're absolutely correct. `/var/lock/subsys/yum-cron` was created after I started `yum-cron`.  What detective skill could I have used to determine a hidden fact like that?  Or is that something that can only be learned from years of work on servers?  It was not mentioned in any of the tutorials I read.

Comment: @stackedAndOverflowed In this case, you can read the unit file itself, e.g. with `systemctl cat yum-cron.service`. But knowing about the semantics of the `/var/lock/subsys/yum-cron` file does require you to have had experience with the previous version of Enterprise Linux.